# Spark: can you include partition columns in output files?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-partitioning

I am using Spark to write out data into partitions. Given a dataset with two columns `(foo, bar)`, if I do `df.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").partitionBy("foo").save("/tmp/output")`, I get an output of

```
/tmp/output/foo=1/X.csv
/tmp/output/foo=2/Y.csv
...
```

However, the output CSV files only contain the value for `bar`, not `foo`. I know the value of `foo` is already captured in the directory name `foo=N`, but is it possible to also include the value of `foo` in the CSV file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only if you make a copy under different name:

```
(df
    .withColumn("foo_", col("foo"))
    .write.mode("overwrite")
    .format("csv").partitionBy("foo_").save("/tmp/output"))
```

Comment: Is this still the best solution to date? What if I want the exact same name?